# Ejecutar el codigo Javascript despues de que html cargo todos los elementos en Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Muy buen día comunidad, tengo un problemita que me viene quebrando la cabeza.
Y es que en todos los navegadores me funciona menos es Chrome.

Lo que quiero es ejecutar una simple función, después de haber cargado todos los elementos de HTML, suena simple y me funciona en todos los navegadores si pongo el script justo antes del < /body>. Pero simplemente no hago que funcione en Google Chrome.

Este seria un ejemplo:
Tengo un archivo html llamado ejemplo.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hola Mundo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ejemplo2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Un parrafo</p>
    <div> Un texto </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    iniciar();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y en mi código JavaScript tengo una primera alerta que se ejecuta antes de los elementos HTML y después la función iniciar que la ejecuto después de cargar todos mis elementos HTML (que dispara Alerta 2), lo cual me funciona en todos los navegadores menos en Google Chrome, en Chrome me dispara ambas alertas y no muestra los elementos HTML hasta después de ejecutar ambas alertas, pensaba que podría ser un tema de actualización o configuración en Chrome.

```js
alert("Alerta 1");

function iniciar (){
    alert("Alerta 2");
}
```

Alguien sabe porque?
Muchas gracias :D
P.D ya lo intente con < script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = iniciar;

< /script > y nada

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno parece que era una simple actualización de Google Chrome, me he descargado la ultima versión y me corre perfecto ahora.

Espero esta pregunta le sirva a alguien en el futuro.

Saludos.

Comment: Cuando pones el recurso JavaScript dentro del header, todas las funciones ya están cargadas antes que los elementos dentro de body, esto significa que puedes invocar funciones dentro del body. Si invocaras una función y el recurso se ubique antes de terminar el body y después de la invocación a la función, se mostrarán errores al no ser declarada la función. 

Comment: Muchas gracias Alex, lo tomare en cuenta.